# Streaming a response in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want CakePHP to stream a download to the browser. The content of the stream is served via an API.

So, CakePHP makes a request to that API, gets a response with a file and must stream this response to the browser.

This is what I got so far:

```
public function getDownload() {

    // do other things

    $http = new Client([
            'headers' => [
                'accept' =>'application/octet-stream'
            ]
        ]);

    $response = $http->get($this->url,[]);

    // first try
    // $stream = new CallbackStream(function () use ($response) {
    //     return $response;
    // });
    // $response = $response->withBody($stream);

    // second try
    // $stream = new CallbackStream($http->get($this->url,[])->getData());
    // $response = $response->withBody($stream);

    return $response;
}
```

With this setup I can download small files. The reason **I need a stream is, because the API could send files up to 10GB**. My guess is, that with `$http->get` CakePHP stores the whole response in memory. Thats why I'm getting a memory exhausted error.

I know I'm lacking a bit of understanding here. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You're going to be very disappointed once you learn about PHP's file serving capabilites :) What API are you using? Can it return a public download URL instead?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution:

```
public function getDownload($url) {

$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"accept: application/octet-stream\r\n"
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$response = new Response();

$file = fopen($url, 'r',false, $context);

$stream = new CallbackStream(function () use ($file) {
    rewind($file);
    fpassthru($file);
    fclose($file);
});

$response = $response->withBody($stream);
return $response;
}
```